# How can I append static word after product name before saving it in database in magento?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I am making a module, where i want to add some static words after product name. Like Product name is "Test product 1" and when i save the product, the product name must save as "Test product 1 Demo" in database. Which file do I need to code for this?

I am using magento 1.9.1.1

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/41277/how-to-create-an-new-observer-on-the-event-catalog-product-save-before - swap the "description" for "name" in that example, it's otherwise identical to this.

Answer (score 0):

Use below syntax in any config.xml of you module.

```
<global>
        <events>
                <catalog_product_save_after>
                            <observers>
                                <yourmodule>
                                    <type>singleton</type>
                                    <class>Namespace_Module_Model_observer</class>
                                    <method>productsaveafter</method>
                                </yourmodule>
                            </observers>
                </catalog_product_save_after>     
        </events>
    </global>

Then create a Observer.php in your model folder.
<?php
class Namespace_Module_Model_Observer
{
public function productsaveafter($observer){

        $product = $observer->getProduct(); 
        $realname=$product->getName();
        $realname.='customstring';
        $product->setName($realname);
        $product->save();
    }
}
```